# highlighting with different heights

Tags: highlighting, soul

I want to use `\hl` from the soul package to highlight my mathematical definitions. The problem is, that it is very inflexible when it comes to height. For example when I write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

We now define \hl{$\widetilde{M}$} and we define \hl{$M$}

\end{document} 

then the tilde will not be highlighted. I saw that one can change the definition of \hl using the following

\makeatletter

 \def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%

 \setul{}{4ex}%         !!!change this value!!! default is 2.5ex

 \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor

 \SOUL@stpreamble}

\makeatother
```

with this definition the tilde will be highlighted, but now for the second definition too much space on top and bottom will be highlighted. So basically I want to use two versions of `\hl`, the normal one and the second one. How can I do this?